# Using LINQ to XML how can I group element on the basis of its value?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, group-by, linq-to-xml

Below is the structure of my xml file:

```
<adlibXML>
   <recordList>
        <record priref="1" selected="False">
              <collection>TEXTILES</collection>
              <someotherelements>xyz</someotherelements>
        </record>
        <record priref="2" selected="False">
                  <collection>CERAMICS</collection>
                  <someotherelements>xyz</someotherelements>
        </record>
        <record priref="3" selected="False">
                  <collection>PAINTING</collection>
                  <someotherelements>xyz</someotherelements>
        </record>
        <record priref="4" selected="False">
                  <collection>TEXTILES</collection>
                  <someotherelements>xyz</someotherelements>
        </record>
   </recordList>
```

I am fetching this xml file using some APIs from a database from a vendor. I have three tables in my new database, Catalogue, Collection and Artifacts.
I want to group the collection element on the basis of its value like 'TEXTILES','CERAMICS' etc. and a counter variable to count the number of collections I have. Using which I can then create collectionID & collectionTitle dynamically in my Collection table.

I am not able to solve it. Till now I have only done this bit of code:

```
var getcontent = from record in xmldoc.Descendants("record")
                 //this group by doesn't work
                 group record by record.Element("collection")
                 select record.Element("collection").Value;                     

foreach (var node in getcontent)
{
    Response.Write("Collection: " + node + "<br/>");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try along the following lines:

```
var groups = from record in xmldoc.Descendants("record")
             group record by (string)record.Element("collection") into g
             select new {
               key = g.Key,
               count = g.Count()
             }

foreach (var group in groups)
{
  Response.Write("Collection " + group.key + " has " + group.count + " member(s).");
}
```

Comment: Hey Martin, your code works for me! Thanks a lot. I have just started using LINQ. So basically what you have done is you have selected the collection element and put that in g kind of variable and then doing operations on g.

Also, I have many xml elements in the file for which I have to get their values and store it in the database. So, can you please tell me an example of code to whether append select a,b,c,d in one code or I need to write the from,select for each element? Hope my point is clear to you!

Thanks again

Comment: I don't see how your second question relates to the first one so you should post a new question instead of asking in a comment. If you are new to LINQ and LINQ to XML you should or at least could start with the introductions on MSDN i.e. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397933.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx. Generally if you want to select values you can do stuff like `from foo in doc.Descendants("foo") select new { bar = (string)foo.Element("bar"), baz = (int)foo.Element("baz"), (DateTime)foo.Element("whatever") }`.

Comment: Alright. Thanks for the resource Martin. I am reading that now.

Cheers!